# How to make an app lock application with pattern,or password

Tags: android

i'm working on applocker application, i have listed all the apps with app icon ,app name and a checkbox to select the app ,now my requirement is when user checks the checkbox, app should be locked with a pin or pattern. I have given the usage access permission. now, how can i achieve the remaining process like monitoring apps, to show the pattern screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot at this would be to build a custom [launcher app](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps).

Then you have control over which apps the user sees, and how to open them. You can implement this pattern/password logic by yourself before opening the apps, and have another activity with the list of apps and checkboxes.

As a starting point, take a look at some open source android launchers like [Lawnchair](https://github.com/LawnchairLauncher/Lawnchair)

Comment: tq so much ,but it is not my requirement. i should be able to lock the apps without custom launcher